# Learning MySql from a Microsoft SQL background

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I'm not sure if this question has been asked before but are there any recommended book for learning MySQL for a SQL server background?

Comment: No book is needed. The majority of skills transfer directly, as ANSI SQL. There are SQL-Server-specific things and MySQL-specific things, and you'll discover them as you go. Spend time with the [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index.html) when you need syntax reference or to lookup a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the MySQL Cookbook by Paul DuBois (O'Reilly) to be a good resource to learn idiomatic MySQL. Having been in a similar situation -- I worked professionally with MS SQL while privately doing very small things in PostgreSQL and later MySQL, my experience has been that you won't have to re-learn too much as both dialects follow the ANSI standard relatively closely.

The above applies to writing SQL code. As for database administration, I'd recommend the official online documentation, and the MySQL Workbench as an admin environment.